# Pyspark - checking Json format using accumulator

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

How do I check JSON file is corrupted like missing {, }, commas or wrong datatype. I am trying to achieve by using accumulator because process runs on multiple executors.

```
spark_config = SparkConf().setAppName(application_name)
ss = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_config).getOrCreate()

class StringAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
  def zero(self, v):
      return []
  def addInPlace(self, variable, value):
      variable.append(value)
      return variable
errorCount = ss.sparkContext.accumulator(0)
errorValues = ss.sparkContext.accumulator("", StringAccumulatorParam())

newSchema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)
    StructField("status", BooleanType(), True)])

errorDF = ss.read.json("/Users/test.jsonl")
errorDF2 = ss.createDataFrame(errorDF, newSchema).cache()

def checkErrorCount(row):
   global errorCount
   errorDF2["id"] = row. newSchema["id"]
      errorCount.add(1)
      errorValues.add(errorDF2["id"])

errorDF.foreach(lambda x: checkErrorCount(x))
print("{} rows had questionable values.".format(errorCount.value))

ss.stop()
```

Here is corrupt JSON file -

```
{"name":"Standards1","id":90,"status":true}
{"name":"Standards2","id":91
{"name":"Standards3","id":92,"status":true}
{"name":781,"id":93,"status":true}
```

Comment: I would probably load the file as a text file. And then write a user-defined function (udf) to attempt to convert each text line to JSON. if it succeeds output 0, otherwise output 1. And then sum the results.

Comment: Another alternative is read the files twice. Once as text to get total number of lines. And then again as json with option mode=DROPMALFORMED to get valid count. The difference is number of bad rows.

Comment: Thanks. I have 40+ good size (MB) files so reading them twice will cross our time limitation to finish job. I have tried using "FAILFAST" but since jobs on multiple executors I was not able to catch exception. 

Is there a way to get number of bad lines only?

Comment: how do I convert each text line to JSON. I have tried textFile("/path/filename.jsonl") but how do I parse this texFile as JSON in Python Spark (PySpark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a play with this and came up with the following.

Of the 2 solutions, I think the difference of counts will be faster since it will use native Spark JSON processing.

The UDF solution will do the JSON parsing in Python, meaning you have to pay the cost of transferring each file line from Java to Python so will probably be slower.

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

application_name = 'Count bad JSON lines'
spark_config = SparkConf().setAppName(application_name)
ss = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_config).getOrCreate()

# Difference of counts solution
input_path = '/baddata.json'
total_lines = ss.read.text(input_path).count()
good_lines = ss.read.option('mode', 'DROPMALFORMED').json(input_path).count()
bad_lines = total_lines - good_lines
print('Found {} bad JSON lines in data'.format(bad_lines))

# Parse JSON with UDF solution
def is_bad(line):
    try:
        json.loads(line)
        return 0
    except ValueError:
        return 1

is_bad_udf = udf(is_bad, LongType())
lines = ss.read.text(input_path)
bad_sum = lines.select(sum(is_bad_udf('value'))).collect()[0][0]
print('Got {} bad lines'.format(bad_sum))

ss.stop()
```